# How to copy file from PC to android tablet?

Tags: android, usb

When I connect the android tablet to windows 7 I get 2 external devices, one of them (H) doesn't open.
[image]

When I open G:, I get this

[image]

If I want to copy an app (adobe reader) to the tablet, to which folder should I copy it?

This is the screen of the tablet:

[image]

Where should I access the folders and files from?

Comment: This question should be on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Any? Copy it over, navigate to the folder on your phone, and click on the APK and it'll install. Make sure you allow your phone to install apps from unknown sources first.

Comment: OK, but how can I access the files and folders from the tablet?

Comment: @metacompactness Install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartwho.SmartFileManager&hl=en from the play store, use that to browser to the apk and install

Comment: But I don't have an internet wifi connection.

Comment: @metacompactness then get access to one? If you cant get Internet access at all, then the question should be, why do you have a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

That folder looks like the Android SD Card. If you copy it to any folder, just browse to it using a File Manager and click it to install it. You could also copy it to Downloads, and then open the Downloads app to install the APK. Make sure you also have enabled Unknown Sources.

Comment: I copy it to the Downloads folder but still android says no downloads